# AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'owner'

Tags: django

Я пытаюсь запретить пользователям удалять посты других пользователей. То есть Вася Пупкин не может удалять посты Ирины Ивановой по `URL`. Для этого я пишу данный код. Но он выдает ошибку `AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'owner'`

views.py

```
@login_required
def deleteAll(request):
    todos = Todo.objects.all().delete()

    if todos.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    return redirect('list:index')
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Todo(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body
```

Интересно то что `raise Http404` работает у меня в коде ниже

```
@login_required
def update(request, pk):
   todo = Todo.objects.get(id=pk)

   if todo.owner != request.user:
      raise Http404
```

И при переходе `update/20` пользователем которому не принадлежит данный пост, он выдает ошибку 404 (чего я и добивался), но с методом `deleteAll` такая фишка не проходит и любой желающий может стереть все посты, всех пользователей, при переходе по `URL`, а я хочу чтобы каждый мог удалять только свои посты и не удаляя чужие. В чем моя ошибка подскажите ? Полная ошибка выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, зачем все эти манипуляции, если можно просто выбирать записи только определённого владельца?

```
@login_required
def delete_all(request):
    Todo.objects.filter(owner=request.user).delete()
    return redirect('list:index')
```

Во-вторых, нужно сначала проверить владельца, а уж потом удалять. Наконец, метод [delete()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects) возвращает кортеж хранящий информацию о том, сколько записей удалено. Естественно, в нём нет поля `owner`.

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло!